# Отображение директивы на определенных страницах. Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Всем привет. Подскажите пожалуйста каким образом можно запретить отображение директивы? К примеру у меня есть 10 страниц и нужно чтобы директива отображалась только на 8-ми из них. При помощи этой директивы выводится изображение на background.
Директива:

```
function bgimage(){
    return{
        restrict: "E",
        replace: true,
        template: "<div class='bg-image'><img src='img/logo-black.svg'></div>"
    }
}
```

Так я ее объявляю в index.html:

```
<body ng-app="app">
   <bgimage></bgimage>
   <main ui-view></main>
</body>
```

Comment: исходя из приведённых данных, кроме логики `<div ng-if='false'><bgimage></bgimage></div>` на этих страницах ничего не приходит :) то есть вместо false будет переменная, которая будет везде true, а на этих страницах false

Comment: @MasterAlex это немного не то. Я использую роутинг и все шаблоны отображаются в  <main ui-view></main>. Но при переходах между шаблонами мне надо что-бы backgraund всегда отображался (не блымал при загрузке) Если я правильно понял вы мне предлагаете разместить <bgimage></bgimage> в каждом шаблоне. Этот вариант не подходит(

Comment: используй второй ui-view

Comment: @Artem, нет, вы меня неправильно поняли, я не предлагаю разместить этот код в каждом шаблоне, я предлагаю сделать логику для его видимости в layout через переменную, которая будет в котроллере или где у вас там определяются роуты и эта переменная будет выдавать false при нужных путях

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил следующим образом:

```
.run(function($rootScope){

    $rootScope.showBg = function(){
        // страницы где background не будет отображаться.
        var pageName = ['/page_1', '/page_2'];
        var location = window.location.pathname;

        if(pageName.indexOf(location) == -1)
            return true
        else 
            return false        
    }
})
```

ну и в index.html:

```
<body ng-app="app">
   <bgimage ng-if='showBg()'></bgimage>
   <main ui-view></main>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Я делал такое, только с анимацией загрузки.
Вам нужно создать базовый контроллер, в нем будет метод который будет отвечать за показ директив на определенных страницах.
Делаете DI `$location`, в методе пишете что-то типа

```
var self = this;

self.routeOnDisplayDirective = ['/path', '/path2'];

self.showDirective = showDirective;

function showDirective () {
    if (self.routeOnDisplayDirective.indexOf($location.path()) !== -1) {
       return true;
    } else return false;
}
```

в нужных вам контроллерах делаете наследование от базового, а потом

```
<bgimage ng-if="ctrl.showDirective()"></bgimage>
```

Comment: я не понял как использовать этот код:)

Comment: если честно, мне тоже не совсем понятно. Но принцип его работы я понял и сделал похожее через $rootScope.